# use redux in existing react native project and how its affect on project

Tags: react-native, react-redux

Hey guys I just started redux for my shopping cart project.

I just use that only for a global counter of cart items. 
 I want to know that if I use redux package in my full completed package just only for counter can I use it?
and If I use redux only for my that component which need to show cart items count. does it affect on my local state.
do I need to restructure my project to be based on redux. 
and does it affect on my local state like this.state

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your redux store will not affect the value of the component assigned to this.state ;
Remember that to access the values of your redux store inside the component you need to use those functions:

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    yourReduxValue: state.yourReducer.yourReduxValue
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    onSomeEvent: passMe => dispatch(someEvent(passMe))
  };
};

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(YourScreen/YourComponent);
```